# rake db:migrate cause StandardError - uninitialized constant CreateObjects::Object

Tags: ruby, activerecord, uninitialized-constant

I have migration 20150930051523_create_objects.rb:

```
class CreateObjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
  create_table :objects do |t|
    t.text :name
    t.timestamps null: false
  end

  Object.create :name => "A"
  Object.create :name => "B"
  Object.create :name => "C"

  end
end
```

```
$ rake:db migrate --trace cause output:
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke db:environment (first_time)
** Execute db:environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20150930051523 CreateObjects: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:objects)
   -> 0.0010s
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

uninitialized constant CreateObjects::Object/db/migrate/20150930051523_create_objects.rb:8:in `change'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:605:in `exec_migration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in '
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `'
NameError: uninitialized constant CreateObjects::Object/db/migrate/20150930051523_create_barbers.rb:8:in `change'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:605:in `exec_migration'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:279:in `measure'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:588:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:587:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:765:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:995:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1041:in `ddl_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:956:in `block in migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:952:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:820:in `up'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/migration.rb:798:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in '
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/rake:23:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Error emerging at Object.create... stage, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by set up pg gem, which pull bundle of another gems and packs (particularly postgresql-server-dev-all). After installing it, the command rake db:migrate works fine and completely.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: In a comment it was pointed out that the actual code was not containing "Object", this answer is thus based on the wrong example.**

`Object` is a bad name to use for an (unscoped) Model class, as it is already defined by Ruby.

The `Object` you are calling create on is probably not the `Object` class you defined in your model sources.

I assume you run rails. Remove the `Object.create` lines from your migration. Run it, it should work fine. Then, call `rails console`, where you end up in a **live** session. Here you can play around with your code, e.g. call `Object.create`, `Object.where{id: 1}` etc. I assume that you will get the same errors.

So, as a solution, rename your `Object` into something else, like `Class` and look if it works.

Okay, that was a joke, of course `Class` is also a really bad name for a model class :) . Try to find something more meaningful.

Comment: Object is a template word, which i used instead of Barber & Barbers:
    class CreateBarbers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
    create_table :barbers do |t|
    t.text :name

    t.timestamps null: false
    end
    Barber.create :name => "Jessie Pinkman"
    Barber.create :name => "Walter White"
    Barber.create :name => "Gus Fring"
    end
    end

Comment: Then please provide actual code in your question ... !

Comment: Thanks, Felix, the problem was solved by set up pg gem, which pull bundle of another gems and packs (particularly postgresql-server-dev-all). After installing it, the command rake db:migrate works fine and completely.

Comment: @irishfromua Great to hear. At Stackoverflow it is important that solved answers are marked as such (this is not fire-and-forget, more like wikipedia), so please update your question, post an answer yourself and accept it. Thanks. And make sure to read the help-section here (top-right).